# Radio button returning previous value selected

Tags: javascript, angular

The below function is called on click of a radio button:

```
  this.selectedMeasures.forEach(measure => {
      console.log(measure);
      console.log(this.form.value[measure.value]);
      if(this.form.value[measure.value] === 'severe')
          this.showDiagnosis = true;
  });
}
```

selectedMeasures is a key value pair array
logging measure always prints when the radio button is clicked
But logging this.form.value[measure.value] only prints when the radio button is clicked twice.

For example, the radio button has a, b, c as values
When a is clicked first, nothing prints.
Then when b is clicked, a then prints.
So it always prints the previous value of the radio button.

Please how can I fix this?

Comment: provided code is not sufficient, please try to provide a stackblitz with the issue replicated for a quick resolution!

Comment: In any case, I would recommend to subscribe for changes through `this.form.valueChanges` instead of listening for a click event.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Dmitry S., it sounds like the issue is that you are having is that you are logging measure using the radio `click` event instead of the `change` event. When the `click` event is fired, the value of the target has not changed to the new value. The `click` event triggers a change in value which in turn triggers the `change` event. The value of the `change` event target value is the new value.